# i want to use ajax variable in other function

Tags: json, ajax, django, modal-dialog

I want to use modal, so i get the data value from ajax.
the data is like that [{'source_name': '인터넷', 'description': '여행자료', 'source_slug': '_1', 'subject_name': '여행', 'subject_slug': '_6'}]

I want to put the value of source_name "인터넷" to source_name variable.
I want to use soure_name variable at this line.

```
html += '<li><span> 출처 : <a href="/tag/' + source_slug + '">' + source_name + '</a>'
```

but source_name is undefined.
please help me

this is code.

```
function showModal(){

          var pk = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
          $.ajax({
            url : '/photo/' + pk + '/',
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
              data= JSON.stringify(data)
              var source_slug = data[0]["source_slug"];
              var source_name = data[0]["source_name"];
              var description = data[0]["description"];
              var subject_slug = data[0]["subject_slug"];
              var subject_name = data[0]["subject_name"];
              }
          });
var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
          var largeImg = $(this).find('img').attr('data-bsp-large-src');
          if(typeof largeImg === 'string'){
                src = largeImg;
          }
          var index = $(this).attr('data-bsp-li-index');
          var ulIndex = $(this).parent('ul').attr('data-bsp-ul-index');
          var ulId = $(this).parent('ul').attr('data-bsp-ul-id');
          var theImg = $(this).find('img');
          var pText = $(this).find('.text').html();        
          var modalText = typeof pText !== 'undefined' ? pText : 'undefined';
          var alt =  typeof theImg.attr('alt') == 'string' ? theImg.attr('alt') : null;

          clicked.img = src;
          clicked.prevImg = parseInt(index) - parseInt(1);
          clicked.nextImg = parseInt(index) + parseInt(1);
          clicked.ulIndex = ulIndex;
          clicked.ulId = ulId;


          $('#bsPhotoGalleryModal').modal();

          var html = '';
          var img = '<img src="' + clicked.img + '" class="img-responsive"/>';

          html += img;
          html += '<span class="' + settings.iconClose + ' bsp-close"></span>';
          html += '<div class="bsp-text-container">';
          html += '<li><span> 출처 : <a href="/tag/' + source_slug + '">' + source_name + '</a>'
          html += '</span></li>'
          html += '<li><span> 과목 및 단원 :<a href="/tag/' + subject_slug + '">' + subject_name + '</a>'
          html += '<li><span>' + description + '</span></li>'
          html += '</div>';
          html += '<a class="bsp-controls next" data-bsp-id="'+clicked.ulId+'" href="'+ (clicked.nextImg) + '"><span class="' + settings.iconRight + '"></span></a>';
          html += '<a class="bsp-controls previous" data-bsp-id="'+clicked.ulId+'" href="' + (clicked.prevImg) + '"><span class="' + settings.iconLeft + '"></span></a>';

          $('#bsPhotoGalleryModal .modal-body').html(html);
          $('.bsp-close').on('click', closeModal);
          showHideControls();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the change inside success not after:

```
function showModal(){

  var pk = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    url : '/photo/' + pk + '/',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
      data= JSON.stringify(data)
      var source_slug = data[0]["source_slug"];
      var source_name = data[0]["source_name"];
      var description = data[0]["description"];
      var subject_slug = data[0]["subject_slug"];
      var subject_name = data[0]["subject_name"];
      var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      var largeImg = $(this).find('img').attr('data-bsp-large-src');
      if(typeof largeImg === 'string'){
            src = largeImg;
      }
      var index = $(this).attr('data-bsp-li-index');
      var ulIndex = $(this).parent('ul').attr('data-bsp-ul-index');
      var ulId = $(this).parent('ul').attr('data-bsp-ul-id');
      var theImg = $(this).find('img');
      var pText = $(this).find('.text').html();        
      var modalText = typeof pText !== 'undefined' ? pText : 'undefined';
      var alt =  typeof theImg.attr('alt') == 'string' ? theImg.attr('alt') : null;

      clicked.img = src;
      clicked.prevImg = parseInt(index) - parseInt(1);
      clicked.nextImg = parseInt(index) + parseInt(1);
      clicked.ulIndex = ulIndex;
      clicked.ulId = ulId;


      $('#bsPhotoGalleryModal').modal();

      var html = '';
      var img = '<img src="' + clicked.img + '" class="img-responsive"/>';

      html += img;
      html += '<span class="' + settings.iconClose + ' bsp-close"></span>';
      html += '<div class="bsp-text-container">';
      html += '<li><span> 출처 : <a href="/tag/' + source_slug + '">' + source_name + '</a>'
      html += '</span></li>'
      html += '<li><span> 과목 및 단원 :<a href="/tag/' + subject_slug + '">' + subject_name + '</a>'
      html += '<li><span>' + description + '</span></li>'
      html += '</div>';
      html += '<a class="bsp-controls next" data-bsp-id="'+clicked.ulId+'" href="'+ (clicked.nextImg) + '"><span class="' + settings.iconRight + '"></span></a>';
      html += '<a class="bsp-controls previous" data-bsp-id="'+clicked.ulId+'" href="' + (clicked.prevImg) + '"><span class="' + settings.iconLeft + '"></span></a>';

      $('#bsPhotoGalleryModal .modal-body').html(html);
      $('.bsp-close').on('click', closeModal);
      showHideControls();
  }
      });}
```